# How to do Convert.ToDateTime or parse date in C# but only get dd/mm/yyyy in C# 2.0?

Tags: c#, datetime-parsing

As topic says, I have a string like

```
string CreatedDate = "12/09/2010"
```

and I want to pass it to a web method that only accepts it as DateTime

```
customer.dateCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(CreatedDate);
```

naturally it add hh:mm:ss after the date which the web service doesn't accept so how can I keep the date in the short format when I convert it to a date?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the web service indeed accepts a parameter of type `DateTime`, how can it *not* accept "hh:mm:ss" after the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have:

```
void WebMethod(DateTime date);
```

and

```
string dateString = "12/09/2010";
```

then do next:

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    WebMethod(date);
}
else
{
    // raise an error - specified date is not in specified format
}
```

Note:

```
date.Hour // 0
date.Minute // 0
date.Seconds // 0
```

---

Otherwise, if you have `DateTime` object and `WebMethod(string date)` where date should be in specified format, then:

```
DateTime date = ..;
WebMethod(date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 2):

A `DateTime` value doesn't know anything its formatting (and indeed it *shouldn't*). It sounds like your web service is broken if it's not accepting standard date/time formatting. What's the implementation of the web service? Is "customer" an autogenerated proxy class?

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` has a `.Date` property that strips the time information.

Comment: As I understand it, that's not the problem - after you've parsed a string which only contains a date, everything will be 0 in the time fields anyway. The problem is when the web service client code formats the date/time in the request.

Comment: "that strips the time information" - yes and no: you get back a `DateTime` with a zero time portion, but it *is* still a `DateTime` value. In particular, invoking `.Date` on the result of the `Convert.ToDateTime` call in the question will return you exactly the same value as the input.

Comment: Alright I am using webservices.netsuite.com/xsd/transactions/v2009_2_0/…  what I just found out is that there's a field called Date Created which gets populated automatically (the field I tried to insert to by using customer.dateCreated) but then deep down in the settings of a customer there's a custom field called Created Date which I should pass my date to. I wonder why createdDate is in the xsd when it gets populated automatically...

Answer (score 1):

Does the WebService accept the date as only "12/09/2010"? Typically a webservice should follow the reccomendations here
[XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime)

Which is UTC format. Using:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(value, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zz00 yyyy", null);
```

solves the problem most times.